# Is there an equivalent to the Anderson-Darling test for categorical data?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, anderson-darling-test, two-sample

I have categorical data of the following form:

```
    |Total|Pos|Neg
In  | 6   | 4 | 2
Out | 11  | 4 | 5
```

There are two categories: In/Out and Positive/Negative. All the elements fall under either In or Out, however the same elements can be either Positive, Negative or None (which is why the second line does not add up to 100%). I would like to know if there is an equivalent of A-D test that I can use to determine whether the categories In and Out are drawn from the same distribution or not on the basis of Pos and Neg.

Comment: Chi sqared test of goodness of fit seems like what you want. http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/goodness-of-fit.aspx?Tutorial=AP

Comment: If yuo had ordered categorical data in your two groups you should be able calculate an Anderson-Darling type of two sample statistic (Pettit test) but the critical values and p-values will be different from the continuous case. However, with only 2x2 (assuming you're going to ignore the 'none's) there's probably little reason to avoid the usual chi-squared test of homogeneity (though if the numbers here are typical that may be a little on the small side for a good approximation with the chi-square distribution) .... however it's *not* a chi-squared goodness of fit test as suggested above.